# Typescript definition for a cefsharp webview interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, definition, cefsharp

I registered a RegisterAsyncJsObject in the CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser. This creates an additional JavaScript object instance in the web browser which looks like this:

```
frame.openWindow(name, data);
frame.navigateToWindow(name, data);
```

It works great with plain JavaScript. I'm able to access to this object and the methods do their job.

Now I want to program against this object with TypeScript, but the TypeScript compiler doesn't know the types of that object. I tried to create a type definition file of that object, but it doesn't really work. it seems if I import a definition / declaration, what ever, it will override the 'frame' object.

Do you have any idea how to use that object in TypeScript ?

Do I really need to have a type definition for that object? And how does it really work?

Until now I just used TypeScript and already done type definitions, but didn't created definitions by my own.

Comment: you could just create a .d.ts files that extends the the frame interface with the extra methods. you can read more about open ended interfaces in typescript here(sample B) https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/interfaces.html

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it. How do I import the d.ts in a right way without overriding the instance of that frame object?

Comment: typescript interfaces are open ended, if you make a new interface with the same name (and module etc) it will just add the new methods you define to the existing one.

Comment: the import is the issue here. see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `frame` doesn't yet have an existing type, you can define your own:

```
interface MyFrame {
    //fill in the `any` and `void` types as appropriate
    openWindow(name: any, data: any): void; 
    navigateToWindow(name: any, data: any): void;
}

//if frame is initialized somewhere else:
declare let frame: MyFrame;

//if you want to initialize it here:
let frame: MyFrame = //some initialization code
```

If `frame` has an existing type, say `HTMLFrameElement` from `lib.d.ts`, then you can add an additional interface to extend the existing one. This is known as [**declaration merging**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces):

```
interface HTMLFrameElement {
    openWindow(name: any, data: any): void; 
    navigateToWindow(name: any, data: any): void;
}
```

This can be done either in a regular Typescript file (`.ts`) or in a definition file (`.d.ts`).

---

You can include the interface + declaration in the current file, and that should allow you to use these methods. If you want to place it in an external file, and in order to let the compiler know about the file, do one of the following:

- Include it in the project's `tsconfig.json`
- Import it into each referencing file with `import "/myfile"`

Comment: Many Thanks. If it's in a separate file (.ts or .d.ts) how do I import this? 

import { frame }... creates a new variable, which overrides my object, even the declaration in the same file were I use the frame.

import * as frame ... wrapps another object around it.

No import works in the IDE, but the TypeScript compiler still misses it

Comment: @JuergenGutsch Do you have a `tsconfig.json` which includes this file? That should be enough. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @JuergenGutsch You should be able to use `import "/myfile"`.

Comment: That's it. Just to tell the compiler where the file is. Many thanks. I use Visual Studio Code. It finds the file because it is  somewhere in the project folder.

Comment: great thanks :) That's what i was looking for. I don't want to add too much to the tsconfig. so this seems to be a clean and easy way :)

Comment: @JuergenGutsch Keep in mind that if you use `import` you'll have to do it in every single file that references these methods. Also, RE _I don't want to add too much to the tsconfig_ -- are you worried about performance? I don't think this is an issue. Or are you worried about making the `tsconfig.json` too complex to understand? You don't necessarily need to specify each and every file in `tsconfig.json`; you can configure directories to exclude or include. See [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder and your support. In this specific case, 'frame' is just used in a single file. So it seems to be fine like this.

Comment: @JuergenGutsch Because if it's only used in a single file, it might be simpler to put the interface in the file directly (outside of any namespaces), instead of a separate file + import.

Comment: i tried it. If I do like this, the let frame: MyFrame; overrides the already existing instance coming from the webview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135933/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-juergen-gutsch).